# Most Recommended approach for continues data sending from android / Iphone to server continuously

Tags: c#, android, .net, iphone, azure

I developing a mobile application(Android & iPhone native) when the user is entered into one module it will send continues geolocation to the server. Once user exit from that module then it will stop sending data. In some case server also want to send continues data to the mobile app( for some time period).

Currently, I planning to use an API(.Net). The mobile application will continuously call this API and transfer the data. The next plan is using web socket for continuous data transfer.

The application will deploy in Azure.

Anyone can suggest, which method(architecture) is most suitable for continues data sending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, there are two Azure services suitable for your scenario: 1) [Azure Storage Queue](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/) 2) [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-functions/). When enable/disable your module, you could send a queue message to Azure Storage queue. The Azure function could based on Azure QueueTrigger. If the queue triggered, then Azure function will stop/start sending data.

Comment: Thanks fo your comments. My issue is which method(architecture) is most suitable for continues data sending. Currently, I planning to use an API(.Net). The mobile application will continuously call this API and transfer the data. The next plan is using web socket for continuous data transfer. can you suggest, which method(architecture) is most suitable

Comment: Based on your description, you want to **continues** sending data via the method(architecture), and want to **continuously** call this API. Does it enough if you only continuously call the API to get the real-time data? If you want to search some API in Azure to handle mobile data. Please try to have a look at [mobile service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/).

Comment: In your point of view which is best approach for sending continues  data from mobile application  to server.

Comment: As I said before, if you want to use Azure, you could choose Azure SQL, and use mobile app to send data to Azure SQL. This url: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started/ will help you understand it. Hope it could give you some tips.